# Need to get option value using option text from drop down select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown as follows:

```
<select id="lang" >
       <option value="1">php</option>
        <option value="2">asp</option>
       <option value="3">java</option>
  </select>
```

I am using `select2.`

I have the option text 'java' with me what I need is I want to get the corresponding option value using select2.

**In this case if my text is java I need value as 3.**

please guide me. See my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o0uxjjtq/260/)

Comment: @Tushar see this question carefully. I want to get using particular text

Comment: [`$('#lang option:contains("java")').val()`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vekmb4yh/)

Comment: Thanks @Tushar this is what I needed. cheers

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o0uxjjtq/261/